# synonym search using apache solr

Tags: solr

I have tried search using Apache SOLR. I have done with the PHP client code for to implement with apache solr. I have indexed using the function solrUpdate and got search results using the funcion solrQuery.

now i want to search using **synonym search** , i.e in previously I ve indexed the title as "money" then, I go to search keyword is "**money**" the results will came nicely. but i want to do with sysnonym search ("money" => "cash" or "currency").

Now i go to search with keyword "**cash**" no results will came? but i am expecting results which have only "money" will be returned.

What should i ve to do? my xml document format is 
"id"   =  123
"name" =  Money 
"description" = Some sample description.

any ideas suggestion most welcome.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If "money", "cash" and "currency" are equivalent in your searches, they should be just separated with comma in your synonyms file: `money, cash, currency`.

For more information see the [documentation on SynonymFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#SynonymFilter).

Comment: once again thanks, its working fine with created synonyms.txt file in /conf location. I need this now to be more sophisticated e.g. I need to be able to create synonym sets with an XML format here. is it possible?

Comment: @prabu: please post another question with more details.

Comment: @prabu What will be the semantic difference between a text file based and a xml file based synonym definition?